# Installing VMware VSA in a closed network

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi

I want to deploy an installation of VMware VSA in my network, and for that I got 2xquad nics in each server (2x Dell PE 1950)

Everything seems fine so far, but then the installer complains about some NFS address conflicts, which I don't get, since it is a completely closed network.

A quick sketch of the network:
[image: Network setup]

So, as you can see, I connect the servers VSA network directly between them.

But is this actually supported, or do I have to use a switch and a routable IP?

My vCenter server is connected via a Site-To-Site VPN on a different subnet.

ESXi servers are in the 192.168.99.X/24 subnet, and the vCenter server is in a 10.100.100.X/24 subnet.

I am configuring VSA for 192.168.253.X/24 as frontend network, and 192.168.254.X/24 as backend network.

I am configuring the portgroups myself, since the installer complains it is not a greenfield install.

```
VSA install configuration:
VSA Management Network Settings:
VSA Cluster IP Address: 192.168.253.10
VSA Cluster Service IP Address: 192.168.253.20

Subnet Mask:    255.255.255.0
Gateway:    192.168.99.1

Host Network Settings:   192.168.99.236
Management IP Address:  192.168.253.210
Datastore IP Address:   192.168.253.220
vSphere Feature IP Address: 192.168.253.254
Subnet Mask:    255.255.255.0
Gateway:    192.168.99.1
Back-end IP Address:    192.168.254.2
Back-end Subnet Mask:   255.255.255.0

Host Network Settings:   192.168.99.235
Management IP Address:  192.168.253.110
Datastore IP Address:   192.168.253.120
vSphere Feature IP Address: 192.168.253.253
Subnet Mask:    255.255.255.0
Gateway:    192.168.99.1
Back-end IP Address:    192.168.254.1
Back-end Subnet Mask:   255.255.255.0

VLAN ID Settings:
Management VLAN ID: 1381
Datastore VLAN ID:  1381
vSphere Feature VLAN ID:    1381
Back-end VLAN ID:   1382

Disk Formatting Option:
Format disks immediately

Storage Capacity Selection:
911.72 GB
```

Here is the warning I get upon starting the install:

[image: Switch warning]

This is the error I get when I try to begin the actual install:

[image: Node error]

This is the overview of the vswitch config:

[image: vswitch1]

This is the config of the frontend network on one of the servers. The rest is configured similary, where the active adapters for the frontend is configured as standby for vmotion and vice versa.

[image: vsa front end]

Comment: I can't see the lack of a switch as being a problem, but you've not stated the actual errors you're getting, also does it work with just a single link?

Comment: How about a screen snapshot of your vSwitch configurations?

Comment: @chopper3: More info and the actual error added.

Comment: @spacemanspiff: screens have been added :)

Comment: @FrederikNielsen - thanks for the extra information, I have to admit I'm not a VSA user, only ever set it up once as part of revision for VCAP but there IS a chance that it demands actual switch ports rather than direct connection - that's a bit stupid if it's the case but the only way to prove it would be to use a switch. I wish I knew a workaround or other answer for you but I don't sorry. I'll be very interested in any further work you do on this issue.

Comment: @chopper3 - thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I cannot test with another switch at the moment, since the rack is totally full :) Other answers are welcome

Comment: @Chopper3 - could it have anything to do with the services being in different subnets?
According to the vSphere documentation ( http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsa.doc_10%2FGUID-3405C258-3476-4461-8BB0-2F279C8F0A94.html ) , they put both vCenter, ESXi hosts and the VSA cluster in the same subnet, while I have those in 3 different subnets..

Comment: Just tried using the same subnet for VSA as for the ESXi, and it came up with a new error: `Cannot create VSA cluster: Unable to login to VMware Cluster Service at: xxxx` - so it seems like there has to be some sort of connectivity going on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, after some weeks of messing around with all this, I decided to put up a switch between the hosts, and it works perfect.

Also a note for the future: The vCenter server **cannot** be on a different subnet - the VSA installer simply won't let you continue.

Comment: How's the performance?

Comment: @ewwhite . Haven't had time to do some actual performance testing on it yet.

Comment: Disregard my comment; different vendor of VSA